# Image in a ScrollViewer in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I have a FlipView which shows the pages of a leaflet as the user swipes through it. I want the user to be able to zoom in a page.
What I found so far is that if I wrap my *Image* inside a *ScrollViewer* and set *ZoomMode = Enabled*, the user can zoom. The strange thing is that if I zoom in the right side of the page, it automatically goes back to the left side after I lift up my fingers from the screen. Any idea how to solve this issue?

XAML:

```
<Grid Name="grRoot">
    <FlipView x:Name="flipView1"
              BorderBrush="Black"
              ItemsSource="{Binding}">

        <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ScrollViewer ZoomMode="Enabled" MinZoomFactor="1">
                    <Image Source="{Binding url_dotcom}"
                           Stretch="Fill" 
                           Holding="imgHolding"/>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </DataTemplate>
        </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
    </FlipView>
</Grid>
```

Setting the FlipView's width and height:

```
flipView1.Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
flipView1.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
```

Comment: I had a very similar problem on Windows 8.1. Almost the same scenario. I found that setting Horizontal and Vertical ScrollBarVisibility to Auto on ScrollViewer helped - but then if the image rendered is bigger than the flipview (which usually is, for zooming to work OK), it was rendered too big. So the other thing I did was to limit the Grid's max width to Window.Current.Bounds.Width and max height to that same width multiplied by scale factor based on your magazine's page format. And then it worked.

Comment: I edited my question and posted the XAML code. Could you edit it and write in what you said?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<Grid Name="grRoot">
    <FlipView x:Name="flipView1"
              BorderBrush="Black"
              ItemsSource="{Binding}">

        <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ScrollViewer ZoomMode="Enabled" MinZoomFactor="1"
                              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <Image Source="{Binding url_dotcom}"
                           Stretch="Fill" 
                           Holding="imgHolding"
                           MaxWidth="{Binding ElementName=YourPage, Path=DataContext.Width}"
                           MaxHeight="{Binding ElementName=YourPage, Path=DataContext.Height}"/>
                </ScrollViewer>
            </DataTemplate>
        </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
    </FlipView>
</Grid>
```

There are 2 important changes here:

- Set ScrollViewer's HorizontalScrollBarVisibility and VerticalScrollBarVisibility to Auto
- Bind Image's MaxWidth and MaxHeight to Window.Current.Bounds.Width and Window.Current.Bounds.Height respectively exposed through Width and Height public properties inside a ViewModel that is a DataContext to that specific page. This is for scenarios where your FlipView is taking up the whole page. If you need the FlipView to be smaller on the page, then set the Width and Height properties in the ViewModel based on the size you expect/need/want.

EDIT:
More info in my blog post [Why is my zoomable ScrollViewer snapping the image to the left?](http://igrali.com/2015/07/16/why-is-my-zoomable-scrollviewer-snapping-the-image-to-the-left)

Comment: The only problem now is that this way, if I swipe left to go to the next leaflet page, the scrollviewer also detects that movement and the image moves slightly left, resulting in a small gap on the right side. Any idea how to resolve this (if possible at all?)